# Dynamic og:image with Variables from original page

Tags: javascript, php, html, meta

I've struggled to find any resources regarding this topic online so I thought I would start a discussion. I'm curious how to make the **og:image** be dynamic depending on the data present from the original URL. For example, [trustpilot.com](http://trustpilot.com) has a dynamic **og:image** for each site that displays the websites name as well as the rating. I had a go at this myself with a Get Request that would contain the necessary information for the image then be redirected to another URL that would generate the image and then finally redirect you to the newly created image, but it didn't really work as I had expected... Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Original URL? As in... a different og:image depending on the referer?

Comment: Yea @AlexM it would be dynamic for the generated image. So for Trustpilot (The example) the og:image is dynamic for each website's status. If that makes sense...

Comment: In that case, kyleplo's answer would do, just replace $_GET['text'] with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (or whatever the framework provides, if you use one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably have some code running on their server that looks at the query parameters and generates an image. This is how you would do this in PHP:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im = imagecreate(400, 30);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $text, $textcolor);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Then set your `og:image` to `yourwebsite.com/generateImage.php?text=Example%20text`

Comment: Sweet thanks :) I'll give it a try, I'll accept the answer once I get it working just to keep the discussion open.